# Access client certificate stored on another computer

Tags: certificates, client-side

We are developing an application, that is using *client certificate* needed for client authentication (HTTPS connection) when using a specific web service.
When a customer company has hundreds of computers, the IT admin has to install this client certificate on each computer (and every year when the client cert is renewed).

My question is, is it possible to have the client certificate in a single place (single computer, server), so all PC clients will *somehow* obtain certificate from this server? But what about the private key, which is needed together with the client cert, during the authentication.

And to make it harder, is there a solution that does not require a more complex hardware solution like a domain (as some customers have only a very simple network with a few computers)?

Thank You for any information.

EDIT:
The client certificates are issued by the organization that operates the webservice. Each company, that uses this webservice, earns only *one* client certificate (so all PC clients within company use the *same* certificate).

Comment: In my opinion the way you intend to use client certificates is wrong. There should not be a single certificate shared between all clients, but instead each client should have its own certificate. A client certificate is used to authenticate a specific endpoint (user with browser) and not a whole company.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I edited my question, added information that one client certificate per one company is correct. Access to webservice is granted per company, not per user.

Comment: What OS are you targeting? Either way there should be a management solution to deploy this for all workstations.

Comment: @Shadi: *"... one client certificate per one company is correct ..."* - it might be correct from the standpoint that you want to do it this way but it is not correct from a standpoint on how client certificates are supposed to be used. By trying to use these in a way which is not intended you create the problems you currently have and which you are asking us to solve.

Comment: @LTPCGO Win7/8/10. It would be fine if there exists a management solution, but customer's ITs evidently do not have any idea, so they are asking me if I can find the solution :)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Just to more explain the situation, solution "one client cert per one company" is designed by the operator of the web service, and as it is (simply said) government webservice running for few years, we have to deal with it.
But your answer seems to be the final answer to my problem. If the solution "one client cert per one company" is not the correct usage of the client certificates, then probably does not exists solution that I am asking for. Thank You very much, it is more clear for me now, how client certificates should be used.

Comment: Without wanting to contradict @SteffenUllrich on the not very recommended setting you are trying to achiever: Would *Download certificate and key from a local webserver by user and install it in the browser* be a valid solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to the comments under my question, I suppose the answer from @SteffenUllrich is the right one:

> "... one client certificate per one company is correct ..." - it might
>   be correct from the standpoint that you want to do it this way but *it
>   is not correct from a standpoint on how client certificates are
>   supposed to be used*. By trying to use these in a way which is not
>   intended you create the problems you currently have and which you are
>   asking us to solve.